# Infinitely Countable Definition of Linear Dependence

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been looking at this definition of [linear dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) which I reproduced below:

> Let $\left \{ v_{i}|i\in I \right \}$ be a family of elements element of a vector space over a field $K$, and let $J$ be a finite subset of $I$ not equal to the null set. A family is **linearly dependent** if there exists a family of elements $\left \{ a_{j}|j\in J \right \}$ where every $a_{j}$ is an element of K and at least some $a_j$ is non-zero such that $ \sum_{j\epsilon J}a_{j}v_{j}=0$, where the index set $J$ is a non-empty, **finite** subset of $I$.

Why is the sum over $j\epsilon J$ and why does it have to be finite? Couldn't you have a set of vectors $\left \{ v_{1}, v_{2} \right\}$ be independent and then just make $|\left \{ a_{j}|j\epsilon J \right \}|<|\left \{ v_{i}|i\epsilon I \right \}|$ and find $\left\{ v_{1} \right\}$ to be dependent making $\left \{ v_{1}, v_{2} \right\}$ be dependent as well (which is not always the case)? I am having a hard time defining what the family of elements $\left \{ a_{j}|j\epsilon J \right \}$ is in this context. Any help would be appreciated. I feel as though I am missing a certain aspect of this definition.

Comment: Because we do not want deal with infinite sum yet. $e^x - \sum_{k = 1}^\infty x^k/(k!) = 0$ but intuitively $e^x$ shall be independent of polynomials...

Comment: What you have is **wrong**.  You don't get to choose the set "J" ahead of time as is implied by what you wrote.  What is correct is that a set of vectors is "dependent" if and only if there **exist** a finite set of indices, J, such that this is true.  J will in general depend on the set of vectors- you do not choose it ahead of time.  And J has to be finite because an infinite sum of vectors is simply not defined in "Linear Algebra".

Comment: I would have thought $\left \{ a_{j}|j\epsilon J \right \}$ should be $\left \{ a_{i}|i\epsilon I \right \}$ and the summation be over $i\epsilon I$.

Comment: @W.G. You can think of a specific example. How would you say the set of vectors $\{(k, 0)|k\in \Bbb{R}\}$ is linearly dependent? (the Mathjax code is $\in$ not $\epsilon$ btw

Comment: In the future, consider using `$i \in I$` rather than `i \epsilon I`.  $i \epsilon I$ is a bit harder to read than $i \in I$.

Comment: @LiChunMin: You could find two columns that are equal and say that those would be dependent because of that. In regards to the problem though (assuming a field of real numbers), I would say that $\{(k, 0)|k\in \Bbb{R}\}=\left \{ v_{i}|i\in \mathbb{R} and v_{i}=\mathbb{i}\right \}$. As far as, $\left \{ a_{j}|j\in J \right \}$ I am not sure. I will use that symbol for now on (it's easier to type anyways).

Comment: @W.G. there are no two columns that are equal if we use each value of $k$ in $(k,0)$ exactly once.

Comment: @W.G. As Mr. O has pointed out, we usually use the convention $\{1,1,2,3\}=\{1,2,3\}$. Try to match the wiki definition with the statement here: " $2(1,0)+(-2,0)=(0,0)$ so that the set of vectors in question is linearly dependent".

Comment: Another thing is that if your set of vector in the question $\{v_i\}_{i \in I}$ is finite, then you can always include all the vectors into the "non-trivial expression of 0". For example, to say $\{(1,0), (-2,0), (3,0)\}$ is linearly independent, we can reuse the previous statement, or say $2(1,0)+(-2,0)+0(3,0)=(0,0)$

Comment: @LiChunMin: Your example cleared up everything for me! Thank you so much! That definition was not apparent to me until you went over how that dependent set was related to $\{(1,0), (-2,0), (3,0)\}$. I admit I messed up that set problem earlier. Thank you for being patient with me. Again, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @W.G. You're welcome! Try turn to examples when you are confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that might clear things up: let $\Bbb N = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$. Let $\Bbb R^ \Bbb N$ denote the space of sequences of real numbers (indexed by $\Bbb N$), a vector field over $\Bbb R$.  For my convenience of notation, I will define a sequence $x \in \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ as a function $x:\Bbb N \to \Bbb R$ (so the "sequence" is $x(1),x(2),x(3),\dots)$.  First, consider $S = \{v_i : i \in \Bbb N\}$  to be the set of sequences defined by
$$
v_i(j) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & i = j\\
0 & i \neq j
\end{cases}
$$
It seems intuitively clear (based on what we know from finite dimensional spaces) that this set should be linearly independent, and indeed it is.  Now, define another sequence $x$
$$
x(1) = 1, \quad x(2) = \frac 12, \quad x(3) =  \frac 13, \quad x(j) = 0 \;\;(j = 4,5,6,\dots)
$$
Take $S_1 = S \cup \{x\}$.  Index its elements so that $v_0 = x$ and $v_1,v_2,\dots$ are the elements described above. It seems intuitively clear that the set $S_1 = S \cup \{x\}$ should be linearly depenedent, and indeed it is.  If we take, for example:
$$
J = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\},\\
a_0 = -1, \quad a_1 = 1, \quad a_2 = \frac 12 , \quad a_3 = \frac 13 , \quad a_4 = a_5 = 0
$$
Then we have $\sum_{j \in J} a_j v_j = 0$, but the elements $a_j$ are not all equal to zero.

On the other hand, lets define
$$
y(j) = \frac 1j  \quad j = 1,2,3,\dots
$$
It might surprise you that the set $S_2 = \{y\} \cup S$ is linearly **independent**.  Index $S_2$ so that $v_0 = y$, in a way analogous to our indexing of $S_1$.  Intuitively, we should think that the set is linearly dependent because if we were to set $a_0 = -1$ and $a_j = \frac 1j$ for $j \in \Bbb N$, then we should have
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j v_j = 0
$$
**However**, the above requires an **infinite sum**.  In vector spaces, it is not generally possible to take infinite sums because taking *infinite* sums requires taking *limits* of finite sums, and there is not necessarily a way to take the limit of a *sequence of vectors*.

Answer (score 0):

Linear independence of a set $\{v_i\mid i\in J\}$ means that for each finite subset $I$ of $J$, the set $\{v_i\mid i\in I\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: I don't see how this answer attempts to answer the question. It would be better as a comment.

Comment: You've considered the complementary assertion: linear dependence means that just one set $\{v_i\mid i\in I\}$ being linearly dependent.

Comment: So I agree that you've correctly (albeit tersely) stated the definition of independence, but I don't agree that this is what the question called for.